# Текст без вертикальных отступов

Tags: html, css

Ссылка на codepen - https://codepen.io/anon/pen/bQmYgm.

```
    <span>SEO</span>

    span{
      font-size: 120px;
      line-height: 1;
    }
```

Как сделать так чтобы текст был во всю высоту родителя (span), т.е. чтобы высота родителя соответствовала размеру шрифта, и чтобы текст был прижат со всех сторон, чтобы не было отступа сверху, снизу, и сбоку?

P.S. Надеюсь понятно объяснил)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В пределах одного элемента, такое невозможно осуществить в полной мере. Но, можно попробовать максимально прижать:

```css
span {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 0.7em;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 240px;
  line-height: 0.7em;
  
  border: 3px dashed #090;
}
```

```html
<span>SEO</span>
```

Как видим, остались отступы по бокам. И здесь не помогут, ни `font-kerning`, ни `letter-spacing`, ни что-либо ещё (где ты, отрицательный *padding*?..)).

Опять же, для каждого шрифта, необходимы свои значения `height` и `line-height`, т.к. существуют весьма специфичные и экзотические шрифты.

Так же, ситуация осложняется тем, что способ выше, хоть как-то работает для текста написанного *заглавными латинскими* буквами. Но, со строчными латинскими или кириллицей, в виду наличия у букв выступающих элементов, такое уже не пройдёт - если равняться по выступающим частям, то текст не будет выглядеть прижатым снизу, к примеру.

Можно попытаться избавиться от отступов по бокам, обернув `span` с текстом ещё одним блоком, и задать ему отрицательные `margin`-ы, `overflow`,`width`... Имхо - *"овчинка выделки не стоит"*. Удачи в экспериментах!